# Creating int find method to find object in array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need help creating a method to find an object in an array and making a loop to change the object.

```
public void changeABFF() {
    System.out.println("Enter first and the last name of the best friend you would like to change: ");
    String fname = keyboard.next();
    String lname = keyboard.next();
    BestFriends other = new BestFriends(fname,lname,"","");

    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0;i<myBFFArray.length && found == false;i++) {
        if(other.equals(myBFFs.get(i))) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println("Enter a First Name: ");
            String fName = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter a Last Name: ");
            String lName = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter a Nick Name: ");
            String nName = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter a phone number");
            String cPhone = keyboard.next();    

            BestFriends tmp = myBFFs.get(i);
            tmp.firstName = fName;
            tmp.setLastname(lName);
            tmp.setNickName(nName);
            tmp.setCellPhone(cPhone);
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm changing from array list to array and changed the name to myBFFArray

My question, is how do I create a find method to match up user input to value in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your BestFriends class to override equals and hashCode to compare two BestFriends objects

```
    public class BestFriends {

        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String nickName;
        private String cellPhone;

public BestFriends(String firstName, String lastName, String nickName, String cellPhone) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.nickName = nickName;
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getNickName() {
            return nickName;
        }

        public void setNickName(String nickName) {
            this.nickName = nickName;
        }

        public String getCellPhone() {
            return cellPhone;
        }

        public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
            this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return this.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            BestFriends bf = (BestFriends) obj;

            return bf.getFirstName().equals(firstName) && bf.getLastName().equals(lastName) && bf.getNickName().equals(nickName) && bf.getCellPhone().equals(cellPhone);
        }
```

After that when you iterate over the array

```
public BestFriends find(String firstName, String lastName, String nickName, String cellPhone) {
        BestFriends bestFriends = new BestFriends(firstName, lastName, nickName, cellPhone);

        for (BestFriends b: myBFFArray) {
            if (b.equals(bestFriends)) {
                return b;
            }
        }
    }
```